# Storing a Reference to multiple objects in a different bounded context using entity framework core 2

Tags: c#, domain-driven-design, entity-framework-core, ddd-repositories

I am trying design driven domain and am using entity framework core. From my understanding of design driven domain I should never reference objects in another bounded context, I can only reference their identifiers.

I have a class A in bounded context A which references many objects of type B in bounded context B like below were A should only store a reference to ids of the B objects.

```
public class A
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public List<int> bIds { get; private set; }
    public int Name { get; private set; }
}

public class B
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int Name { get; private set; }
}
```

How do I describe that relationship configuration in the Fluent API? 
If I don't add any configuration then I get the error The property "'A.bIds' is of type 'List' which is not supported by current database provider. ".

Thanks

Comment: What if you use `ICollection` or `IList`, like `public ICollection<int> bIds { get; private set; }`

Comment: Hi Hackerman, that doesn't seem to work either. "The property 'Wedding.InvitationIds' could not be mapped, because it is of type 'ICollection<int>' which is not a supported primitive type or a valid entity type. Either explicitly map this property...". I think I may have the entire thing backwards. I have added "public int AId { get; private set; }" to class B and I think this will do what I need. If I have an instance of A I can get all the instances of B which are linked to A with an EF query. I may have misunderstood the DDD guides I was reading. Thanks for taking the time to have a look.

Answer (score 0):

The important point is that these two are separate from each other Bounded Context(BC).
If you want to use class B in Bounded Context(BC) A and in the aggregate where the class A is located, class B should be in this ValueObject`s role. 
And so if you want to communicate between two Bounded Context(BC), you can use Domain Events.